# why is the emitter shooting out in a little striaght line and not the materal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

this has happened before, and I just delete and start over and that is getting really old. I have attached an partial system to a material and it is shooting the particle in a straight line like it is only working off the little dot that the arrows are attached to. the first partial system is a baked system on a different cache file. that one is working but I am trying to eliminate having to back look change bake and look again cycle this puts me in. (smoke and fire)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes when a particle system fails for me I turn the eye button off. Then go back to the start frame and turn it on again. This seems to clear any broken buffer.

Comment: The idiosyncrasies of Blender, where's the book on that one? (rolls eyes) thanks for the tip.

Comment: Did it help tho?

Comment: No, but I did manage to finally get what I was looking to get, but render times rep frame, wow 1:xx:xx.xx @ 200 x 8 cores. that is hours:min:secs.th-secs right?

Comment: Hmmm, IIRC it goes down to tenths of a second